# How to get timestamp from date string with locale timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to parse json items with a date field formated as follows:

```
'Wed, 14 May 2014 20:19:00 BST'
```

How can I get the timestamp from this kind of string ?

Constructing a Date object doesn't work as it gives me an "Invalid Date"

PS: server's clock is set to another timezone than 
BST so stripping out BST from the string does not work

Comment: You could strip out the 'BST' `(var d = 'Wed, 14 May 2014 20:19:00 BST'; d = d.replace('BST', ''); d = new Date(d);`

Comment: If you have access to the server-side code, you should change the date format in the server-side or to represent the date in unix time to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: this would only work if the server's clock was also set to BST though which is not my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/eu/bst.html) `BST` means `UTC +1`, so you could simply replace `BST` with `+0100`:

```
var date = new Date('Wed, 14 May 2014 20:19:00 BST'.replace('BST', '+0100');
```